# Problem with SPI when using rf24 NRF24L01 transceiver with LED matrix MD_MAX72xx

Tags: arduino-mega, led, library, spi, nrf24l01+

I am currently using Arduino Mega to use a LED matrix and a NRF24L01 transceiver.

for LED matrix, I use MD_MAX72xx library. While for the transceiver I use the RF24 library.

I am already able to interface Arduino using two different LED matrix, and two matrix board is already using the SPI.

But when I try to add the RF24 library, and radio.begin(); the LED matrix isn't working properly anymore.

Here is my whole code:

```
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Servo.h>

#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

#define PRINT(s, v) { Serial.print(F(s)); Serial.print(v); }

#define BUF_SIZE      75  // text buffer size
#define CHAR_SPACING  3   // pixels between characters
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
#define MAX_DEVICES 4

const int buzzer_pin = 26;
const int servo_pin = 28;

unsigned long buzz_time;
unsigned long sys_time;
String buzz_type = "off";
int buzz_count = 0;
char charr[50];

Servo myservo;

RF24 radio(30, 32); // CE, CSN
const byte address[6] = "GLN71";
//const byte address[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};

struct LineDefinition
{
  MD_MAX72XX  mx;
  char    message[BUF_SIZE];
  boolean newMessageAvailable;    // true if new message arrived
};

struct LineDefinition  Line[] =
{
  { MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, 51, 52, 53, MAX_DEVICES), "MAX", true },
  { MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, 51, 52,  49, MAX_DEVICES), "MAX", true }
};

#define MAX_LINES   (sizeof(Line)/sizeof(LineDefinition))

void printText(uint8_t lineID, uint8_t modStart, uint8_t modEnd, char *pMsg)
// Print the text string to the LED matrix modules specified.
// Message area is padded with blank columns after printing.
{
  uint8_t   state = 0;
  uint8_t   curLen;
  uint16_t  showLen;
  uint8_t   cBuf[8];
  int16_t   col = ((modEnd + 1) * COL_SIZE) - 1;

  Line[lineID].mx.control(modStart, modEnd, MD_MAX72XX::UPDATE, MD_MAX72XX::OFF);

  do     // finite state machine to print the characters in the space available
  {
    switch(state)
    {
      case 0: // Load the next character from the font table
        // if we reached end of message, reset the message pointer
        if (*pMsg == '\0')
        {
          showLen = col - (modEnd * COL_SIZE);  // padding characters
          state = 2;
          break;
        }

        // retrieve the next character form the font file
        showLen = Line[lineID].mx.getChar(*pMsg++, sizeof(cBuf)/sizeof(cBuf[0]), cBuf);
        curLen = 0;
        state++;
        // !! deliberately fall through to next state to start displaying

      case 1: // display the next part of the character
        Line[lineID].mx.setColumn(col--, cBuf[curLen++]);

        // done with font character, now display the space between chars
        if (curLen == showLen)
        {
          showLen = CHAR_SPACING;
          state = 2;
        }
        break;

      case 2: // initialize state for displaying empty columns
        curLen = 0;
        state++;
        // fall through

      case 3: // display inter-character spacing or end of message padding (blank columns)
        Line[lineID].mx.setColumn(col--, 0);
        curLen++;
        if (curLen == showLen)
          state = 0;
        break;

      default:
        col = -1;   // this definitely ends the do loop
    }
  } while (col >= (modStart * COL_SIZE));

  Line[lineID].mx.control(modStart, modEnd, MD_MAX72XX::UPDATE, MD_MAX72XX::ON);
}

void buzz_start(){
    buzz_count = 5;
    buzz_time = millis();
}

void buzz_call(){
  if(buzz_count > 0){
    if(millis() >= buzz_time){
      if(buzz_type == "off"){
        tone(buzzer_pin, 1000);
        buzz_type = "on";
      }else{
        noTone(buzzer_pin);
        buzz_type = "off";
        buzz_count--;
      }
      buzz_time = millis() + 300;
    }
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  pinMode(buzzer_pin, OUTPUT);

  myservo.attach(servo_pin);

  tone(buzzer_pin, 1000);
  Serial.println("BEGIN");





  for (uint8_t i=0; i<MAX_LINES; i++){
    Line[i].mx.begin();
  }

  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(20, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.startListening();

  String charrr = "STOP";
  charrr.toCharArray(charr, 50);
  printText(1, 0, MAX_DEVICES-1, charr);

  myservo.write(90);
  delay(500);
  myservo.write(180);

  noTone(buzzer_pin);
  sys_time = millis();
}

int counter = 10;
int disp = 0;
void loop()
{
  String charrr = String(counter);
  charrr.toCharArray(charr, 50);
  printText(0, 0, MAX_DEVICES-1, charr);
  if(counter == 0){
    counter = 9;
    if(disp == 0){
     disp = 1; 
     String charrr = "  GO";
     charrr.toCharArray(charr, 50);
     printText(1, 0, MAX_DEVICES-1, charr);
     myservo.write(90);
     buzz_start();
    }else{
     disp = 0;
     String charrr = "STOP";
     charrr.toCharArray(charr, 50);
     printText(1, 0, MAX_DEVICES-1, charr);
     buzz_start();
     myservo.write(180);
    }
  }
  if(millis() >= sys_time){
    counter--;
    sys_time = millis() + 1000;  
  }

  buzz_call();

}
```

I think the problem here is not connection, but with the initalization of the RF24, and radio.begin();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the source code of the MD_MAX72XX library. The constructor with SPI pins starts software SPI.

Use the `MD_MAX72XX::MD_MAX72XX(moduleType_t mod, uint8_t csPin, uint8_t numDevices):` constructor to work with SPI hardware/library with all devices.

```
struct LineDefinition  Line[] =
{
  { MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, 53, MAX_DEVICES), "MAX", true },
  { MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, 49, MAX_DEVICES), "MAX", true }
};
```

Or if the MD_MAX72XX worked for you with software SPI, then use some other pins then hardware SPI pins to make hardware SPI free for the NRF24L01.

```
struct LineDefinition  Line[] =
{
  { MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, SW_SPI_SI, SW_SPI_CLK, MAX1_CS, MAX_DEVICES), "MAX", true },
  { MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, SW_SPI_SI, SW_SPI_CLK, MAX2_CS, MAX_DEVICES), "MAX", true }
};
```

Comment: are you suggesting that, to initialize the transciever (rf24), instead of radio.begin();.... I should use `MD_MAX72XX::MD_MAX72XX(moduleType_t mod, uint8_t csPin, uint8_t numDevices):` ?

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I changed the SI, and CLK. `{ MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, 11, 8, 53, MAX_DEVICES), "MAX", true },
  { MD_MAX72XX(HARDWARE_TYPE, 11, 8,  49, MAX_DEVICES), "MAX", true }` Then the pins 50,51,52 are now used by the NRF24